# Little's formula in a M/G/k queue

Tags: queueing-theory

I found many example of usage of the Little's formula in *M/G/1* queues, but more in general, is it possible to use **Little's Law in a *M/G/k* queue**?

Comment: Use LaTeX please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Little's Law is incredibly general and can apply to $M/G/k$ and other queuing systems.